# How to handle internal service-to-service authentication in an SOA environment

Tags: jwt, microservices, soa

I'm building an SOA architecture which consists of a simple NGINX-based API gateway which forwards calls from browser clients to an appropriate backend API based on their prefix, for example:

- `/auth/login` will route the call to the `login` endpoint on the Authentication service
- `/users/update/widget-1` will route the call to the `update` endpoint on the Users service

etc.

Each service has its own datastore and follows `SOLID` design principles. I use events on a queue to keep services informed about interesting things that happen to data that they both know about. For example, both the Users service and the Authentication service need to store the user's email address as it's used for authentication and emailing. So when a user's email is changed I queue a 'user email change' event onto a User Events queue. The Authentication service subscribes to this queue and uses the event to keep itself up to date.

For simple events, I can include enough details in the event to avoid needing more information. But, thinking ahead, what if a lot of changes have happened to the user and I have a datawarehouse that subscribes to every event type. I don't want to start having huge events - I would rather just include enough information for the interested service to use the event to trigger a call to ask for more details.

So the sequence in this example would be:

1. Client synchronously calls `user update` with JWT bearer token
2. User update service validates JWT and uses it to carry out the update
3. User update service generates a 'user updated' event to the queue, containing the User ID
4. Datawarehouse picks up the event and calls a 'get user details' endpoint on the User service to get full details of the update.

How do I authenticate the 'internal service call'? I can't use the original JWT as the internal request is happening asynchronously and the calling service doesn't have the JWT. It might not even be valid any more by the time the Datawarehouse requests the user details. It feels like I need some 'internal' JWT - for example, in this case, would the answer be for the Datawarehouse service to have the ability to generate its own JWT with its own private key then the User service checks the signature using the Datawarehouse service's public key? In which case, doesn't this mean each service would have to know about all the other services that could call it?

If it helps, my current implementation uses Lumen for the services with the `jwt-auth` package to check the JWT at the API level.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: why do you need to auth internal calls in the first place? if you want to auth internal requests, you have to pass some data on who is asking and what is that service/person/client ... requesting for. based on that, you can check the authentication and apply authorization in place.... dwh service inquiry might have some application account .. but I do not suggest using queues to feed the DWH .. instead, fix (if not already done) your application database so you can easily identify inserted/updated records and get only those in batches (usually nightly)

Comment: on top of that, I am not sure why do you have to catch all changes in the DWH :) is there any business case for intra-day changes? If I change my name from Peter to Paul forth and back 10times a day, what's important is the last change in the day right? You don't have to store the complete history .. that would require a lot of storage space!

Comment: @Mr.P We cannot do nightly batches - different services have different requirements in terms of speed of update, some are immediate. The queue is fundamental to SOA and allows us to independently scale services and workers based on their performance needs. It needs to be driven by queue events.

Comment: for the authentication itself, you can use "application account" which will authenticate the very same way any other client does :)

Comment: @Mr.P An example is if the user email changes, that is needed right away so auth continues to work. Auth also shares some data e.g. whether the account is locked out/not yet activated.

Comment: Perhaps, given your system, it would be worth using OpenId Connect, for example with IdentityServer. Then, the validation of your token would be responsibility of the Identity Server, decoupling itself from the other apps. You could then employ user-machine or machine-machine auth flows. Though, it requires some time to implement

Comment: @sg4c well for the auth/user services it makes sense to sync them right away... for DWH I don't see the necessity :) anyway, if you really want to have that implemented, that use an application account to access the queue ... which queue are you using?

Comment: @Mr.P We are using Google PubSub as the queue - I agree it seems application accounts are the way ahead but my concern is that each request would have to call the auth service to get a JWT before calling the endpoint on the other service. Which seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: @NPinheiro Thanks for the suggestion, I will have a look at OpenID Connect. We ended up implementing our own Auth service as we have some very specific requirements in terms of two-factor auth support which don't seem to be met by any third-party auth providers.

Comment: @sg4c not at all .. .you can only authenticate against the queue.. for the information about the change is in the queue right? You don't have to call it all over again ... queue should store all the changes for a defined period of time ... not really familiar with PubSub specifically, but it seems it works great there too

[PubSub Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/authentication)
[PubSub history](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview)

Comment: @Mr.P No, not all the information about the change might be in the queue. That's my concern - I don't want to design a system that requires everything to be in the event payload or I may get to a point in future where the events are very big.

Comment: so what you are saying is that some of the changes are processed via the msg queue and some are not? is that correct? and you need to project all changes (no matter queued or directly changed) to all systems real-time ?